# Eclipse indigo won't start

Tags: eclipse

This is what is in the log file:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-01-18 09:16:30.495
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.iovMax()I
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.iovMax(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Util.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.getChannel(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.Locker_JavaNio.lock(Locker_JavaNio.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.lock(StorageManager.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initFileManager(BaseStorage.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initialize(BaseStorage.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.initialize(Framework.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

This happened after I made a system restore which (I think) reverted a java update. How do I solve this? I have a tun of stuff in eclipse and I don't want to redo it all again.

ADD:
Meanwhile I got Juno and it seems to be working. But, on my PC, juno has some issues with the shortcut keys and with about 12 plugins I use (they didn't update yet). Does this information help?

Comment: I got that message with Eclipse juno a few days ago. The problem was just gone after a restart of my computer. I guess you can give it a try.

Comment: You can unzip a new copy of Eclipse to a different directory without losing any of your workspace files.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc It's not just workspace stuff. It's also a nice big list of configurations and plugins and configurations to plugins. It takes hours to complete.

Comment: @Magus restarted twice, didn't solve. Any other maybe useful ideas?

Comment: Just tried, I'm unable to start any eclipse indigo or Helios... Any clue about what's wrong?

Comment: is your eclise a 64-bit version and java 32 bit

Comment: This is already solved, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it!

I updated java, rebooted, then uninstalled java, rebooted then installed java.

(rebooting was essential, I tried without rebooting and it didn't work)

now it's working as it should.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Eclipse is using java 1.7. Try to run Eclipse with a different vm. Install java 1.6 and edit the eclipse.ini adding the correspondent argument below, as described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value%3a_Windows_Example)

-vm C:\Java\JDK\1.6\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: That's not the right command, but anyway, I had already tried that one, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: -vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: I just gave an example. That depends on where Java has been installed.

Comment: Oh! ok, ok... Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0):

Backup your .metadata folder, delete it, and try to start Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow
Open eclipse.ini file
You can see below 2 line :

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

Now add below lines mention between Blockquote to set vm properly as per you jdk version

> Blockquote

-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javaw.exe

-XX:-UserCompressedOops

-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll

> Blockquote

before
-vmargs

Comment: Hi Samir - your question is quite difficult to understand, because all the lines are being run together. Can you [edit] your question to use markdown to make your question more readable?